# Shoudl AMCL attempt to respect/get hints from walls?

Tags: localization, navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get localization with AMCL working well. It seems more than happy to allow it's pose estimates to drive right through the walls on my map - shouldn't it take their location as a hint?

Here's a random screenshot of my robot driving around:
[http://i.imgur.com/wWlyo.png](https://i.imgur.com/wWlyo.png)

It's going down the hallway that has most of the red arrows in it. Notice that the arrows on the bottom have driven through a wall - I'd imagine they would bunch up against it, reducing the error of estimates?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9527/shoudl-amcl-attempt-to-respect/get-hints-from-walls?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL handles this sort of issue implicitly through weighting and resampling. The particles in seemingly ridiculous locations likely have very low probability, and should disappear through resampling. If this is consistently not happening, I would bet that something is wrong with your sensor or motion model (which can be controlled through [a bunch of parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl#Parameters)).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-03-22**:
You might take a look at turtlebot_apps stack -- there is an AMCL launch file configured for the create/kinect: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-22**:
Honestly, I have no set any of those parameters beyond the initial pose. Could anyone suggest any important things to set for a standard irobot create / kinect setup?